# Search Fasta file in python, return read efficiently

Tags: python, csv, fasta

beginner here. I want to write a function in python that searches a fasta file for the name of a gene and then return the appropriate read corresponding to it.

FASTA file example:

```
>name1
AATTCCGG
>name2
ATCGATCG
```

My code so far(very rudimentary):

```
def findseq(name):
    with open('cel39.fa', 'rb') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for i in csv_reader:
            if i == '>' + name:
                return i+1
                break
```

This doesn't actually work because I can't return 'i+1'. Also I can iterate of the len(csv_reader) because 'len' is not an attribute. Also I'm not sure if there is a more efficient (but simple) searching system so that I wouldn't need to iterate over the whole file (would be thousands of lines) every time.

Specifically, is there a better way to read Fasta files? Is there a way I can return my read?

```
findseq(name1)
```

should return 'AATTCCGG'

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at a the python library: [Biothon](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page)

It contains a plethora of useful tools and methods.

Here is their example for parsing a fasta file:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("ls_orchid.fasta", "fasta"):
    print(seq_record.id)
    print(repr(seq_record.seq))
    print(len(seq_record))
```

This example prints out all the records in the fasta file.

For your purpose:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("ls_orchid.fasta", "fasta"):
    if seq_record.id == name:
        return seq_record.seq
```

Answer (score 0):

Since FASTA files sequences extend to multiple lines, you will have to concatenate lines till the next instance of > is found. The code below makes a dictionary with gene names as the key and the gene sequence as the value.

```
with open('cel39.fa', 'rb') as fp:
    lines = fp.read().splitlines()

geneDict = {}

# Just to start populating the dictionary later
geneName = 'dummy'
fastaSeq = ''

for line in lines:
    if line[0] == '>':
        geneDict.update({geneName: fastaSeq})
        geneName = line[1:]
        fastaSeq = ''
    else:
        fastaSeq += line

geneDict.update({geneName: fastaSeq}) # Putting the values from the last loop
geneDict.pop('dummy') # Now removing the dummy

print geneDict['name1']
print geneDict['name2']
```

And it prints:

```
AATTCCGG
ATCGATCG
```